# QGIS Virtual Layers based on WFS fail to load on re-opening project

Tags: qgis, wfs, virtual-layer

I have created virtual layers that use WFS layers as one of their sources. Usually, it is an intersection between the WFS layer and a local polygon layer. I embed all the sources. However, when I reload the project, the handle bad layers dialogue comes up and it is unable to resolve the source. Is there a way to reliably use WFS layers within virtual layers?